# Break beam sensor to replace piezo transducer

Tags: sensor, piezo

I have a device intended to sound an alarm and flash a bright light when it detects a phone ringing (so you can hear the phone ringing in noisy environments like workshops). I want to repurpose it to let me know when my woodshop dust bin is full.

The device came with a piezo transducer as a sensor. It connects to the main device via a small cable wires to a 1/8” jack with two contacts. For my project I’d like to figure out how to swap in a IR break-beam sensor instead. Any tips?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Piezo will produce AC pulses from vibration; break beam sensor will produce a DC level change. Good luck.

Comment: try to reverse engineer the device

Answer (score 1):

This is a dead end. It's easier to design a beam sensor-triggered flasher (DC, relatively reliable currents) from scratch than it would be to convert a piezo signal (very low currents, AC) sensing circuit.

So use your break-beam sensors to trigger a flasher. There's **a lot** of "flasher circuits" out there, and it's also not hard to figure out how to amplify the signal from the sensor. Good fun!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your ring detector senses an AC signal on the 2.5mm jack.

You need to make the infrared beam detector produce an an AC signal when the infrared beam is blocked

so you need a circuit to drive the beam sender and a circuit that monitors the beam receiver and makes an AC signal (eg a noise-making circuit) when the beam receiver sees nothing.